# How do I launch my app from a bash script passing in a parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms, bash, powershell

I have a C# Windows Form application that does the following:

1. Shows a list of sync "profiles"
2. The user can select a "profile" and click "Run"
3. The "profile" information is kept in a profiles.xml file and is edited dynamically

If I were to create this into a .exe that could be executed from PowerShell or the command line, how would I program it so that the user can specify which profile to run? For example, instead of clicking a profile and selecting "run", I'd like the user to run the following from the command line:

`sync.exe "profile name or id"`

How do I program my .exe to run like this and how do I handle the incoming args?

Comment: Just look up "C# command-line arguments". That is what you want.

Comment: Yes that is it, thank you!!! Will you put that in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use command-line arguments. To do that in C#, do the following:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // args are your command-line arguments
    // here we check that there was one argument provided, and show a message if there wasn't
    if (args.Length != 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Usage: sync.exe [profile-name]");
        System.Exit(1);
    }
    string profileName = args[0];
    // do stuff with the profile name
}
```